# Identify first node after source node having two neighbors in NetworkX DiGraph

Tags: python, networkx

I am implementing a DiGraph with NetworkX. The source is the red-node. I need to identify the first node starting at the red one that has two neighbors (in "flow-direction"). If I iterate over all nodes - it seems like ramdom. Would be great if someone could help!

[image]

Comment: you don't need to iterate over all the nodes, you start at the source and recursive iterate over successors until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `successors` method. If your DiGraph instance is called G, and your red node has index 0 then you can take a [breadth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) approach like this:

```
import networkx as nx

# Construct graph from example image, all edges pointing away from source
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_path([0,1,2,3,4])
G.add_path([1,5])
G.add_path([3,6])
G.add_path([2,7,8])

# Find first with 2 neighbors
neighbors = G.successors(0)
for n in neighbors:
    nneighbors = set(G.successors(n))
    if len(nneighbors) == 2:
        print "Found", n
        break
    neighbors.extend(nneighbors)
```

The `neighbors` method is interchangable with `successors` for a DiGraph in networkx. If you want to also count ingoing edges for each node, add `G.predecessors(n)` to the set of `nneighbors` when you count them, but remember to not include them in the set when you extend `neighbors`. The code would then be:

```
# Find first with 2 neighbors
neighbors = G.successors(0)
for n in neighbors:
    if len(G.predecessors(n)+G.successors(n)) == 2:
        print "Found", n
        break
    nneighbors = set(G.successors(n))
    neighbors.extend(nneighbors)
```

Comment: For a DiGraph, there's a lot less confusion if you use the explicit `successors` and `predecessors` versions...

Comment: It would be worth using the words "breadth-first search" in your answer somewhere.